# TFS 2010 Automated Build Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, continuous-integration, build-automation

I'm looking to create an automatic build server which runs either when the developer check in changes to a solution or a certain time frame is reached (say 24 hours).

I've looked around, and from what I understand - VS2010 has a different CI to older version, and as such, I can't find much information regarding such a process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both of your suggested options are built into the Build definition in TFS 2010.

Go to: TFS Explorer->Builds->New Build Definition->Trigger

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here's a good tutorial to get you started:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jasonz/tutorial-getting-started-with-tfs-in-vs2010)